# Unable to Create a systemuser in Dynamics CRM 365 online

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

On update field of contact record I want to create a systemuser(user) in dynamics crm 365 online.but I’m getting error like "usersettings With Id = 5fe33120-607f-e811-a95c-000d3af29269 Does Not Exist"

This is the below code I'm trying to create a user

```
Entity getEntity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
                string str = getEntity.Attributes["new_isaeon"].ToString();

                if (str != null && str == "True")
                {
                    // http://localhost:51625/api/Users
                    Entity sysuser = new Entity("systemuser");
                    sysuser.Attributes["fullname"] = "hsk";
                    sysuser.Attributes["internalemailaddress"] = "projectservice_9@crmdemo.dynamics.com";
                    sysuser.Attributes["domainname"] = "projectservice_9@crmdemo.dynamics.com";
                    Guid getGuid = new Guid("700F2217-786A-E811-A95A-000D3AF2793E");
                    sysuser.Attributes["businessunitid"] = new EntityReference("businessunit", getGuid);
                    sysuser.FormattedValues["accessmode"] = "Read-Write";
                    Guid getuserid = service.Create(sysuser);

                }
```

can anyone help me on this thanks.

Comment: If your domain is static like your snippet, you will be only be able to execute this once. As the domain name must be unique, have you already created a user with this domain name ?

Comment: not yet created any user.throwing that error usersettings with id does not exists

Comment: Checking the [doc sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602984.aspx) it looks like the domain name is using `domain\login` syntax

Comment: BTW, is it 2011 or 365? Those two behave different...

Comment: it is dynamics-365 online

Comment: Can you try to remove the line `sysuser.FormattedValues["accessmode"] = "Read-Write";` and see if that executes.

Comment: removed.same error getting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: Recently we started importing users in CRM online directly using OOB CSV import (this is new for me too), it will succeed, and later on when license assigned for same user - this wont create another user record, instead it will map the Azure object GUID to the existing user record based on username/domain name/email. This is more useful when creating stub users without license or roles quickly.

---

In Dynamics 365 CRM online, system users record creation/enabling flow happens from O365 Admin portal end. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/create-users-assign-online-security-roles)

Steps go like this:

1. Security group has to be created in Active directory & mapped in O365 Admin portal for any CRM Org
2. Users has to be added in that AD Security group
3. All the users from SG will be replicated as system users in CRM instance
4. In O365 Admin portal, on assigning CRM license (Basic/Pro) against the user - the system user record will be enabled in CRM
5. In CRM side, we will assign Security role to complete user on-boarding

We cannot create system user using SDK directly because of above manual steps outside CRM online. Can be created using PowerShell like [answered in community](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/104204).

Comment: Though it does not apply to this use case, it is worth noting here that while creating regular users requires the Office365 Portal, it is possible to create Application users directly in D365 Online.

Answer (score 3):

//Use below code to create User in D365

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;

namespace PowerApps.Samples
{
    public partial class SampleProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            JObject azureUser = new JObject();
            JObject retrievedResult;
            string queryOptions = string.Empty;
            string domainName = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter domain name.");
                domainName = Console.ReadLine();

                string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connect"].ConnectionString;

                using (HttpClient client = SampleHelpers.GetHttpClient(
                    connectionString,
                    SampleHelpers.clientId,
                    SampleHelpers.redirectUrl,
                    "v9.1"))
                {

                    queryOptions = "systemusers?$select=domainname&$filter=domainname eq '" + domainName + "'";

                    HttpResponseMessage retrieveResponse = client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress.AbsoluteUri + queryOptions,
                        HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;

                    if (retrieveResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode) //200
                    {
                        retrievedResult = JObject.Parse(retrieveResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                        string outputDomainname = (string)retrievedResult.SelectToken("value[0].domainname");
                        Console.WriteLine("Domain: " + outputDomainname);
                        if (outputDomainname == null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Adding user to Azure AD..");

                            HttpRequestMessage createrequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,
                                client.BaseAddress + "systemusers");

                            Console.WriteLine("Enter first name");
                            azureUser.Add("firstname", Console.ReadLine());

                            Console.WriteLine("Enter last name");
                            azureUser.Add("lastname", Console.ReadLine());

                            Console.WriteLine("Enter internal email address");
                            azureUser.Add("internalemailaddress", Console.ReadLine());

                            azureUser.Add("isdisabled", false);
                  
                            azureUser.Add("caltype", 7);
                            azureUser.Add("businessunitid@odata.bind", "/businessunits(8c44c8ac-f6a3-ea11-a812-000d3a0a74cb)");

                            createrequest.Content = new StringContent(azureUser.ToString());
                            createrequest.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

                            HttpResponseMessage createResponse = client.SendAsync(createrequest, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;
                            if (createResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Account created");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                throw new Exception(string.Format("Failed to Post Records", createResponse.ReasonPhrase));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Failed to retrieve domain: {0}",
                            retrieveResponse.ReasonPhrase);
                        throw new Exception(string.Format("Failed to retrieve domain: {0}", retrieveResponse.Content));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SampleHelpers.DisplayException(ex);
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to exit the program.");

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```