# How to set lookup field with id of a user record just created?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, entity-relationship

I am getting `error - no service provision`, someone with experience please help me.

```
    var clinic = new new_clinic();
            clinic.new_name = "Medinet";

            Account trust = new Account();
            trust.Name = "bIRMINGHAM CITY hOSPITAL";
            Guid trustID = (Guid)Service().Create(trust);

            CrmEntityReference clinic_trust = new CrmEntityReference(trust.LogicalName, trustID);
            clinic.new_Trust = clinic_trust;
            clinic.new_ClinicDate = DateTime.Now;

            new_hospital hospital = new new_hospital();
            hospital.new_name = "Geek-guru";
            Service().Create(hospital);
            Guid hospitalID = (Guid)hospital.Id;
            clinic.new_HostingHospital = new CrmEntityReference(hospital.LogicalName, hospitalID);

            clinic.new_ClinicDate = new DateTime(2018, 07, 28);

            new_serviceprovision ser_contract = new new_serviceprovision();
            ser_contract.new_Trust = clinic_trust;
            ser_contract.new_Specialty = new OptionSetValue(100000018);
            Service().Create(ser_contract);
            Guid ser_con_id = (Guid)ser_contract.Id;
            clinic.new_ServiceContract = new CrmEntityReference(ser_contract.LogicalName, ser_con_id);

            // Account account =  (Account)GetOrgService().Retrieve(trust.LogicalName, trustID, new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ColumnSet("name"));

            //retreive the default business unit needed to create the user
            QueryExpression businessUnitQuery = new QueryExpression
            {
                EntityName = BusinessUnit.EntityLogicalName,
                ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("businessunitid"),
                Criteria = { Conditions = { new ConditionExpression("parentbusinessunitid", ConditionOperator.Null) } }
            };

            BusinessUnit businessUnit = Service().RetrieveMultiple(businessUnitQuery).Entities[0].ToEntity<BusinessUnit>();



            //creating a user
            SystemUser systemUser = new SystemUser();
            systemUser.DomainName = "" + "Chika";
            systemUser.FirstName = "Olabajo";
            systemUser.LastName = "Boss";
            systemUser.InternalEMailAddress = "onyebuchi@gmail.com";
            systemUser.BusinessUnitId = new EntityReference(BusinessUnit.EntityLogicalName, businessUnit.Id);
            Guid systemID = (Guid)Service().Create(systemUser);

           // systemUser = (SystemUser)Service().Retrieve(systemUser.LogicalName, systemID, new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ColumnSet("fullname"));

            //this field is a lookup field to User. Assigned to the user created above
            clinic.new_ClinicCoordinator = new CrmEntityReference(systemUser.LogicalName, systemID);

            clinic.new_BookedBy = new OptionSetValue(100000001);
            clinic.new_Type1 = new OptionSetValue(100000008);
            clinic.new_Type2 = new OptionSetValue(100000001);
            clinic.new_NumberofConsultants = 5;
            clinic.new_NumberofNursesSuppliedByTrust = 6;


            Service().Create(clinic);//getting error here
            MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully added a clinic record");
```

I have been on these for weeks now, I would appreciate a little bit of help.
I am now having "no serviceprivison issue", A user has now been created, but still gettting error.

Comment: Where is this code running, console app or plugin? Put try catch? Did you debug? You tagged 2011 & online - Is it online, then you cannot create user like this.

Comment: It is running in a windows form, using early bound class and the Dynamic CRM is online.

Comment: @ArunVinoth hi Arun, trhanks for the response, but it is not being created, because the id is just zeros.

Comment: @ArunVinoth see here, it was done in the sdk, i did same thing but getting an error. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602984.aspx

Comment: It’s code sample for on-premise not online; also note that you are not passing domain name & business unit values in request which are mandatory.

Comment: @ArunVinoth I have now passed domain name(POSTED MY FULL CODE), which is empty and i think a user has been created, but still getting this error -"System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1: 'new_serviceprovision With Id = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Does Not Exist'"

Comment: So it’s on-premise crm not online. Repeat the steps in answer for debugging issues. Learn some development  basics, you will love coding..

Comment: @ArunVinoth Thanks bro, i will post the result in approximately 5 hours, please be there, as no one ever answers my post on here. Thanks again

Comment: @ArunVinoth I have debugged it and everything produced the expected values, but only got error at the final service.Create().

Comment: @ArunVinoth this worked, thabnks alot Arn for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go step by step. You have 3 things one after other like Creating user, Retrieving FullName column, then updating `clinic.new_ClinicCoordinator` field. Comment out the 2 steps & verify if user is getting created or not, if created successfully then retrieve next (this is not needed as you already have systemID which is needed for update)
2. Use try catch for better exception handling in code

Edit: CRM online interactive user cannot be created in code. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51173756/7920473)

Update:
Merge the below lines, as `ser_contract` object is not updated back with created Guid. Do the same for `hospitalID` as well.

```
Service().Create(ser_contract);
Guid ser_con_id = (Guid)ser_contract.Id;
```

This should be working:

```
Guid ser_con_id = Service().Create(ser_contract);
```